# Intersection of a quadratic form and a degree 3 polynomial

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I encountered this problem during my studies of algebraic geometry. It says:

Let $f=x^3+y^3+z^3$ and let $X$ be the curve in $P^2$ defined by $f$. Find
and describe the locus in $P^5$ of irreducible quadratic forms
$g$ such that if $Y$ is the curve defined by $g$ then $X$ intersects $Y$ at exactly 6 distinct points.

The only idea I have is trying to find the relation the coefficients of $g$ need to satisfy (e.g. irreducibility of $g$). Another thing I was thinking is using Bezout's theorem, but, if I am correct, $f$ is already irreducible, hence $f$ and $g$ always intersect in 6 points (the product of the degrees of $f$ and $g$ is 6). Does someone know how to proceed?

Comment: In maxima CAS `(%i1) resultant(x^3+y^3+1,a*x^2+b*x*y+c*y^2+d*x+e*y+f,y);`
`(%o1) (c^3+3*a*b*c-b^3+a^3)*x^6+((3*a*c-3*b^2)*e+(3*b*c+3*a^2)*d)*x^5+((3*b*c+3*a^2)*f-3*b*e^2+3*c*d*e+3*a*d^2)*x^4+((3*c*e+6*a*d)*f-e^3+d^3+2*c^3+3*a*b*c-b^3)*x^3+(3*a*f^2+3*d^2*f+(3*a*c-3*b^2)*e+3*b*c*d)*x^2+(3*d*f^2+3*b*c*f-3*b*e^2+3*c*d*e)*x+f^3+3*c*e*f-e^3+c^3`

Comment: @abcX: If $C_1,C_2 \subseteq \mathbb{P}^2_k$ are two irreducible curves of degree $2,3$, it follows from Bezout theorem that the intersection $C_1 \cap C_2:=\{P_1,..,,P_d\}$ is a finite set of points and where the intersection multiplicity of $C_1\cap C_2$ at $P_i$ is $m_i$: It follows $\sum_i m_i=6.$ Hence you want $m_i=1$ for all $i$. Do you know the definition of the notion "intersection multiplicity"?

Comment: Include this definition in the post and also some ideas on how you want to use this definition to solve the problem.

Comment: The only definition of multiplicity we have seen is (wlog. we define the multiplicity at zero and in the affine case) $$\text{Mult}_0(V\cap l)=\sup\{m\in\mathbb{N}\,|\,t^m \text{divides } \phi_l(f_i) \text{for all } i=1...r\}$$ where $f_1...f_r$ generate the ideal of $V$, $l=\{(ta_1...ta_n)\,|\,t\in \mathbb{C}\}$ a line containing zero and $\phi_l(x_i)=ta_i$

Comment: Over the reals $x^3+y^3+z^3=0$ and $(5/4)x^2+6xy+4y^2+6xz+8yz+3.99z^2=0$ in the screen $z=1$ the two curves do intersect in [6 points.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zEeL.png)